# modeling with exponential distributions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

The following is an exercise in stochastic modeling.

[image]

Denote the event be $S$ and let $X,Y,Z$ denote the service times of J, P and N respectively. Then $X,Y,Z\sim Exp(\lambda)$.

Could anybody tell me how to write down the event "Naomi is still in the post office after the other two have left"? I suppose this must be related to the service times, but I don't see how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that Naomi walks up to the first available clerk, we observe that Naomi cannot begin being served until one of John or Paul has already left.  Therefore, $$Z > \max(X,Y) - \min(X,Y)$$ captures the event that Naomi remains in the office after both John and Paul have left.

Why is the answer not simply $Z > \max(X,Y)$?  Because Naomi's service time does not begin until the amount of time $\min(X,Y)$ has elapsed.

To give an example, suppose $X = 1$ and $Y = 3$ (in minutes).  Then Naomi begins to be served at time $t = 1$ minute.  She will remain after both John and Paul have left if and only if her service time is longer than $2$ minutes.  This is precisely $\max(X,Y) - \min(X,Y) = 3 - 1$.

Comment: Hmm, $\max(X,Y)-\min(X,Y)$ is just $|X-Y|$.