# a follow up question about modeling with exponential distributions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

This is a follow up question to a previous [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1625182/9464):

[image]

Here is my **question**:

> What if we change the assumption in (a) that the two clerks have different service rates $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$?

---

Thanks to the answer of the previous question, one needs to calculate
$$
P(Z>|X-Y|)
$$
where $X,Y,Z$ denote the service time for J, P and N. I think one also has
$$
f_{Z|W}(z|w)=\lambda_1e^{\lambda_1z},\quad w>0,z>0
$$
and 
$$
f_{Z|W}(z|w)=\lambda_2e^{\lambda_2z}, \quad w<0,z>0
$$
where $W=Y-X$. I don't see how to go on.

Comment: Let $t_i$ be the time the $i$th person is done. Then $P=P(t_3>t_2>t_1)+P(t_3>t_1>t_2)=\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2} \frac {\lambda_2}{\lambda_2+\lambda_3}+\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2} \frac {\lambda_1} {\lambda_1+\lambda_3}$

Comment: How do you decide $\lambda_3$?

Comment: My bad. I assigned $\lambda$'s to customers, not clerks. Set $\lambda_3$ to $\lambda_1$ in the first summand and to $\lambda_2$ in the second and hence we get $P\le \frac 1 2$.

Comment: So $P=\frac{a}{a+b}\frac{b}{b+a}+\frac{b}{a+b}\frac{a}{a+b}$ where $a=\lambda_1$ and $b=\lambda_2$

Comment: @A.S. Are you using $P=P(t_3>t_2\mid t_2>t_1)P(t_2>t_1)+P(t_3>t_1\mid t_1>t_2)P(t_1>t_2)$? Or how do you get the summand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that Naomi always goes to the clerk that finishes first.  Consequently, the behavior of Naomi's random service time is dependent on whether she goes to the first or second clerk (which we will assume to have service rates of $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$, respectively).  To this end, consider the joint distribution of the random service times of John and Paul:  $$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_X(x) f_Y(y) = \lambda_1 \lambda_2 e^{-(\lambda_1 x + \lambda_2 y)}, \quad x, y > 0,$$ where we have assumed without loss of generality that John went to clerk 1, and Paul went to clerk 2.  Then the probability that Naomi is still waiting when both have left is $$\Pr[Z > |X-Y|] = \Pr[(Z > X-Y) \cap (X > Y)] + \Pr[(Z > Y-X) \cap (X \le Y)].$$  Considering the first term, we have $$\Pr[(Z > X-Y) \cap (X > Y)] = \int_{y=0}^\infty \int_{x=y}^\infty (1 - F_Y(x-y)) f_{X,Y}(x,y) \, dx \, dy.$$  This is because the service time $Z$ follows the distribution of whichever clerk finished first, and in this case, it was $Y$.  I leave it to you to show that this integral is equal to $$\frac{\lambda_1 \lambda_2}{(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)^2},$$ and consequently by symmetry, $$\Pr[Z > |X-Y|] = \frac{2\lambda_1 \lambda_2}{(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)^2}.$$