# another follow up question: modeling with exponential distributions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

This a follow up question to the previous two:

- [modeling with exponential distributions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1625182/9464)
- [a follow up question about modeling with exponential distributions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1627264/9464)

[image]

I'm trying to do (c).

---

Denote the service time for John, Paul and Naomi as $X,Y,Z$ respectively and let $W=X-Y$. Let $T$ be the time Naomi spends in the post office. Then

$$
\begin{align*}
E(T)&=E(E(T|W))=E(T|W>0)P(W>0)+E(T|W<0)P(W<0)\\
&=E(Z+Y|W>0)P(W>0)+E(Z+X|W<0)P(W<0)\\
&=\left(\frac{1}{\lambda_2}+\frac{1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}\right)\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}
+\left(\frac{1}{\lambda_1}+\frac{1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}\right)\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}\\
&=\frac{3}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}<
\max\left\{1/\lambda_1,1/\lambda_2\right\}
\end{align*}
$$

But I don't see how to get the answer $c=2+\sqrt{3}$.

(Thanks to Did's comment, one should not consider $E(Z)$ as the time Naomi spends in the offices.)

Comment: The trouble is that $E(Z\mid X>Y)\ne1/\lambda_2$ and $E(Z\mid X<Y)\ne1/\lambda_1$, actually $1/\lambda_1$ and $1/\lambda_2$ measure the mean service time of Naomi, while you are asked about the whole time she spends in the office.

Comment: Why $E(Z\mid X>Y)\neq 1/\lambda_2$ and $E(Z\mid X<Y)\neq 1/\lambda_1$?

Comment: I love the rhetorical question after you modified your post...

Comment: @Did: I agree with your previous comment that $Z$ is the service time of Naomi instead of the whole time she spends in the office. I edited what I got accordingly. The definition of $Z$ remains the same. I think the question why $E(Z\mid X>Y)\neq1/\lambda_2$ and $E(Z\mid X<Y)\neq1/\lambda_1$ makes sense. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Hint: if I'm doing the math right, Naomi's total time simplifies to 3/(lam1+lam2)

Comment: I am getting $c=2$ assuming that the formula for $E(T)$ is right.

Comment: Am I doing the math right? Does the total time simplify to 3/(lambda1+lambda2)?

Comment: I don't understand the downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite the symbols $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ as $a$ and $b$ respectively. The key point is that we are comparing Naomi's average waiting time to **the average waiting time of John and Paul averaged together**.

If one changes $\max\{1/a,1/b\}$ in OP to 
$$
\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}\right)
$$
then one would get
$$
\frac{3}{a+b}<\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}\right)
$$
which would gives the correct answer $c=2+\sqrt{3}$.

Answer (score -1):

Let N, J and P be the service times of Noami, John and Paul.  You have to find the expected time of event N< P-J

The probability distribution of N = P - J with parameter, $\lambda1$ and $\lambda2$ is a Laplace distribution  with pdf

$f_{N}(n) = \dfrac{e^{\frac{n}{\lambda_2}}}{\lambda_1 + \lambda_2}$ for n<0

$= \dfrac{e^{-\frac{n}{\lambda_1}}}{\lambda_1 + \lambda_2}$ for n>0

Find the expected value of this distribution and using the convention of the problem

$E(N) = \frac{(2\lambda_1 \lambda_2)}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2} $

Let $\lambda_2$>$\lambda_1$.. In other words, max($\lambda_1$,$\lambda_2$) = $\lambda_2$ and min($\lambda_1$,$\lambda_2$) = $\lambda_1$

We also know that $E(N)\lt max(E(P),E(J))$

Using the convention of the problem, where meantime is $\frac{1}{\lambda}$

This implies
$\frac{2\lambda_1\lambda_2}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}<\frac{1}{\lambda_2}$

$\lambda_2 \gt 2\lambda_1$

In other words, 
max($\lambda_1$,$\lambda_2$) > 2.min($\lambda_1$,$\lambda_2$)

**Goes to prove that c = 2**

I don't get the number $2+\sqrt{3}$